# echo first group in perl

Tags: command-line, bash, perl

Is there a more elegant perl command for this?

```
ps -ejH | grep 'bash' | head -1 | perl -E ' if( <> =~ /(bash)/) {say $1}'
```

I just want to `echo` the PID which is the first group of chars.

Comment: If you're just trying to find the oldest process whose name matches `bash`, you can use `pgrep -o bash`

Comment: @steeldriver  Please make that an actual answer

Answer (score 5):

Turn Perl's `autosplit` on. It splits the lines into the array `@F` (on whitespace), so `$F[0]` contains the first column.

```
ps -ejH | perl -a -E 'if (/bash/) {say $F[0]; last;}'
```

You can also get rid of the `grep` and `head` commands because *grepping* is a thing Perl can do quite good.

The `head` can be replaced with a call to `last` which breaks the implicit `while(<>){...}` loop imposed by the `-a` switch. On older Perls (before v5.20) you might also need the `-n` switch but [nowadays `-a` implies `-n`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#%2A-F%2A-now-implies-%2A-a%2A-and-%2A-a%2A-implies-%2A-n%2A).

---

Although I love Perl, I'd do this particular one with `awk`:

```
ps -ejH | awk '/bash/ {print $1; exit}'
```

Comment: You're not using `-n` or `-p` so you don't have a while loop, so last serves  no purpose.

Comment: @glennjackman [Since Perl v5.20 `-a` implies `-n`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#%2A-F%2A-now-implies-%2A-a%2A-and-%2A-a%2A-implies-%2A-n%2A) (and `-F` (which we don't need here) implies `-a`). Thank you for pointing out. I updated my post and clarified.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `sed`

```
ps -ejH | sed -n '/bash/{s/^ *\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;p;q}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ejH | perl -n0E 'say /(\d+).*bash/'
```

or

```
pgrep bash | tail -1
```